# Trying to find a comic strip about "What your clothes say about you"

Tags: identification-request, comics

I recall a comic strip about the statement that your clothes make, but don't seem to be able to find it. It goes something like this:

> Cartoon of a Guy with great hair, smile, and a suit.
> Caption: "I'm going places so I won't be here long enough to learn your name".
>
> Cartoon of a Guy in a dirty t-shirt (note mustard stain) and flip flops.
> Caption: "I'm the only one who understands the unix system. Worship me".

There were more panels in between but I don't remember them. I think it's a Dilbert strip.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it:

[image: comic strip]

[Apparently](http://blog.abhinavagarwal.net/2010/08/dilbert-build-better-life-by-stealing.html) this is from the book **[*Build a Better Life by Stealing Office Supplies: Dogbert's Big Book of Business*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0836217578)** - many thanks to @Carmeister for knowing this!

**How I found it:** a Google image search for `comic strip unix "clothes say" about you` (note the quotes) led me to [this page](https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~esj/work.html). Having found the image, I tried [searching for an exact quote](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22understands+the+computer+system+worship+me%22) but found almost no results, probably because Google doesn't index text found in images like this.

Comment: This is closer than anything I've found. Could have sworn there was a mark labeled "mustard stain". Nice work.

Comment: I recognize this comic. I'm almost sure it's from [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Build-Better-Stealing-Office-Supplies/dp/0836217578), but I don't have it handy to check.

Comment: @candied_orange The fact that the last guy's caption was *exactly*, word for word except "unix", the same as what you said in the question - that was enough to convince me. Unless this is lifted from another comic with the same wording but more detailed pictures.

Comment: @Carmeister [yep that's the book](http://blog.abhinavagarwal.net/2010/08/dilbert-build-better-life-by-stealing.html?m=1). Thanks!